# what does "Color me nonplussed" mean?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

This is a technical text

> Looking back at the code, anyone that's not a member of
>   [db_accessadmin] or [db_owner] is going to attempt to run a DBCC
>   command they aren't authorized to run. **Color me nonplussed**. Maybe the
>   developer knows something I don't. But since the command is
>   undocumented, all I can do is guess.

I can't find a reference to this expression. What does it means?

Comment: The expression is _color me_  +  any adjective you want to add.

Comment: though *nonplussed* apparently has [two opposite meanings](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nonplussed). Here meaning 1 (so surprised and confused that one is unsure how to react) is probably intended

Comment: color me = call me. So, given the context of the text, read it as, *call me surprised and confused* or *I am surprised and confused*.

Comment: @Cascabel That's the question I link in my comment lol ;)

Comment: @Hank Oops! Not really sure if this post is closable based on that...but it resolves it for me.

Comment: @Cascabel Yeah I thought the same thing. The OP is technically about the entire phrase so that's why I never voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

> Nonplussed - "state where 'nothing more' can be done or said," from
>   Latin non plus "no more, no further".
>   [1](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=nonplussed)

"Color me" can be translated as "consider me". [2](http://www.word-detective.com/2012/12/color-me-adjective/)

"Color me nonplussed" can then be understood to mean "consider me at a standstill" or "consider me stunned".

@Henry 's second meaning though also applies.  "Consider me not surprised" fits nicely.

Comment: Regarding the second meaning, I would not be surprised that running a command that the user isn't authorized to run ends badly.